# Browser redirect tool?

Tags: browser, redirect

I need to create a tool that sits in Windows in the background and everytime a certain web page is entered, e.g. www.google.com, the tool should automatically redirect to another site.

(Not intended to be a virus, I promise. There is actually a genuine need for this for a client.)

Is this feasible? I know there are lots of viruses/spyware that do this so it should be quite simple to implement?

Comment: Why a tool?  Why not just edit the hosts file so that www.google.com resolves to the other site?  Or is it more than just the domain and needs to be something more specific on the target site?

Comment: It is just the domain. e.g. www.google.com would need to redirect to www.mysite.com/Redirect.aspx?=google.com 

Can I create a tool to edit the hosts file without being blocked by AV scanners? Or is the only way to do this by manually editing the file?

Comment: If you are the system administrator, you can set a group policy to do it. Instructions here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_23790188.html; scroll to post ID 22684061.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).